# how to parse .asn file to managable object in javascript or python

Tags: javascript, python, html, asn.1

I am creating a website which can upload .asn file, fill the parameter, send the request and show the response in html.
I am thinking that I could use javascript to parse the .asn file in order to show the imput and the response result.
But I am having trouble deal with this.
Do I have to write my own parser to do it or is there any tools?
I will appreciate any help, thanks.

update:
I am using flask with javascript so that a python solution can also solve this problem

Comment: https://github.com/indutny/asn1.js ?

Comment: @MattTheNinja thanks but no, what i need is not the path between binay file and .asn file. I need to parse asn file to a tree form so that i can somehow display it on the html with javascript. a python solution can also be nice because i am using flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have a solution to this, This python package: https://github.com/kimgr/asn1ate
create a semantic tree so that I can somehow turn it to json form to diaplay.